# Netbeans and Maven, Clean and Build with dependent projects

Tags: java, maven, netbeans

I have a maven project in Netbeans which depend on other maven projects, 
when i perform clean and build only the current project getting clean and build - can i somehow make netbeans perform clean and build for every dependent project?

the reason that i often need to perform clean and build is because for some reason netbeans does not execute annotation processing on regular build and when i change my annotation processor i need that all my projects will get clean and build...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common requirement when you have some core project depending on many dependent projects. So, you would like to first build all the dependent projects and then the core project and package it.

Normally this is done using some Aggreator-project which will just contain a `pom.xml` file which will invoke the pom of all other projects. Below is one of the sample pom file which will server your purpose.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>BuildAggregator</groupId>
    <artifactId>BuildAggregator</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>aggregator Project</name>
    <description>All module aggregator Project</description>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <modules>
        <module>../DependentProject1-jar</module>
        <module>../CoreProject-jar</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

Notice the module section, you just have to change it with your pom project names.

So, this will make things very handy. That is whenever you want to build all the project you just have to run this `BuildAggregator` project and it will do all the build and packaging task (assuming your standalone pom doesn't have any issue, as it will cause build fail and will show you the reason in console.)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `call` command to execute your mvn processes, like:

```
call mvn clean build install -U
```

for further help execute.

```
help call
```